# How to retrieve Contact created date

Tags: xconnect

I'm using `Sitecore 9.1 update 1`.

When retrieving contacts via `IAsyncQueryable<Contact> queryable = client.Contacts` I don't see the created date of the contact.

How can I programmatically get the contact's created date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible by default. There is a **LastModified** property but it will not serve your purpose.

You should:

- **Create a Custom Facet**: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-custom-facet.html
- **Define** a property to store the **Created date**
- **Set Facet**: At the time of creation of a new contact, set the facet property as described here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/set-contact-facets.html

Answer (score 0):

Xconnect is a stand-alone service from Sitecore 9 which can be used by any client to create and manage user’s data. below link gives an idea how contacts will be managed.
Hope this helps.

- Create and manage contacts: https://sitecorelava.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/sitecore-9-xconnect-as-a-kernel-less-stand-alone-service-to-create-manage-contacts-its-offline-interactions-into-xdb/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).